# What is the common roots of $x^{k_1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $x^{k_2} \equiv 1 \pmod n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

I'm tried to find the common roots of the below system. Say the $k_i$ are natural numbers. ($1 \leq i \leq 2$)

$$\begin{cases}x^{k_1} \equiv 1 \pmod n\\  x^{k_2} \equiv 1 \pmod n  \end{cases}$$

In this post $U(\mathbb{Z}_n) = \{a \vert \gcd(a,n)=1\}$ for the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

If we consider the roots of the $x^{k_1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, the order of them would be divisor of the $k_1$ in the $U(\mathbb{Z}_n) $.  Plus the order of the roots are divisor of the $k_2$ vice versa for the $x^{k_2} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ in the $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. Consequently, the order of the common roots are divisors of the $\gcd(k_1,k_2)$
So, my guess is

$$\begin{cases}x^{k_1} \equiv 1 \pmod n\\  x^{k_2} \equiv 1 \pmod n  \end{cases} \iff x^{\gcd(k_1,k_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

So If we find the all the roots of the $x^{\gcd(k_1,k_2)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$, Then that is all the common roots of the system. Is my guess right? Thinking the $n=p$ (prime number), the above guess fine to me. But I can't confidenlty say "yes" for the $n$ is composite number.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. For a different argument you may consider Bezout's identity. There exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that
$$uk_1+vk_2=\gcd(k_1,k_2).$$ If $x^{k_1}$ and $x^{k_1}$ are both congruent to $1$, then surely the same holds for $x^{uk_1+vk_2}$. In some sense all this is buried into the properties of the order of an element in a group.